# Play framework: play.api.mvc.DefaultJWTCookieDataCodec decode: could not decode JWT: null

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework, nullpointerexception

I keep getting a lot of these warnings:

```
play.api.mvc.DefaultJWTCookieDataCodec decode: could not decode JWT: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec.$anonfun$decode$7(Cookie.scala:649)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.$anonfun$foreach$3(MapLike.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:912)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
```

I have no idea from where they come or why or how or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, where do we start.

Do you happen to have something like this in your code?

`Redirect(...).flashing("error" -> null)`

You see, the "flash" mechanism in Play uses cookies for storing the values, and it just so happens that the "JWT cookie decoder" really dislikes `null` values. First, it breaks the flash mechanism where it is used, and once the `null` is in there, it starts throwing around these warnings more or
less everywhere.

But, but, but, you say, I'm a Scala developer! I never use `null`!

Very well. But do you ever use `ex.getMessage` where `ex` is any arbitrary `Exception`?

Thought so. You see, `Exception#getMessage` may return `null`. In particular, `NullPointerException#getMessage` *does* return the *value* `null` instead of the string "null"!

Yikes.

Anyway, so if you have something like:

```
case Failure(ex) =>
  Redirect(...).flashing("error" -> ex.getMessage)
```

that is the likely culprit.